# Redux вопрос архитектуры

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Я осваиваю веб разработку и у меня созрел вопрос:

- В компонентах реакта должна размещаться логика внутренних состояний и оторбражения.
- В редукторах размещается логика изменения общего состояния.

Где должны размещаться механизмы такие как: запросы к API, промежуточные обработчики, фоновые задачи? Возможно тут нужна сага?

Comment: Рекомендую Саги, можно сделать что угодно с сетевым стеком, подключить другие источники событий/данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На главной странице [Redux Saga](https://ru.redux-saga.js.org/) даже имеется такой абзац:

> Redux Saga — это библиотека, которая призвана упростить и улучшить
>   побочные эффекты (т.е. такие действия, как асинхронные операции,
>   например, загрузки данных, и "грязные" действия, такие, как доступ к
>   браузерному кешу), сделать лёгкими в тестировании и лучше справляться
>   с ошибками.

Такие механизмы как: запросы к API, промежуточные обработчики, фоновые задачи, работа со сторейджем вполне себе могут располагаться в сагах. Это хорошее решение, которое так или иначе само собой напрашивается к Вашему вопросу. Тем более Redux у Вас уже есть, а Redux Saga — это мидлвар Redux, и не составит особого труда внедрить это в проект.

На личном опыте могу с уверенностью сказать, что благодаря Redux Saga в проекте наводится порядок. Большая часть бизнес логики также может перемещаться в отдельные саги, это удобный инструмент, с которым удобно работать и который в свою очередь дает Вам возможность делать компоненты более легкими, разместить логику порционно, что впоследствии будет только "радовать глаз". Да, Вам нужна Redux Saga.

Answer (score 0):

я бы в свою очередь советовал ознакомиться с понятиям middleware, и только затем ознакомиться **со всеми** самыми востребованными сайд-эффектами (`redux-thunk`, `saga`), так как для этих сайд-эффектов, как и для всего возможного в разработке, можно применить селекцию - простые сайд-эффекты(для простых задач, к примеру `redux-thunk`) и сложные сайд-эффекты(для сложных задач, к примеру `saga`).
если будет совсем туго, то [эта](https://iamakulov.com/talks/redux-in-real-life/) статья Вам поможет